# How do I make my (derived?) python instance attributes "self-update" based on alterations to other same-instance attributes?

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes, instance

I know that I have a misunderstanding of how Python attributes work because I'm here writing this problem, but I don't know exactly what I'm misunderstanding. I'm trying to get

```
self.card = self.hand[self.card_number].split()
self.card_val = deck.ranks.get(self.card[0])
```

to attain their values based on `self.hand`, which I pass to `__init__` upon instantiation. Throughout the game I am altering `.hand`, and I want `.card` & `.card_val` to change every time I change `.hand`, instead of having to tell it to do that elsewhere (outside of the attribute definitions). I know there is a way to do this, or at least I think there is, and by that I mean simply by defining their values as inherited based on whatever `.hand` is at any given time, without calling an internal or external function.

In the posted code, I have altered it to work as the game instructions require, using...

```
def get_card_vals(p1, p2):
    for player in [p1, p2]:
        player.card = player.hand[player.card_number].split()
        player.card_val = deck.ranks.get(player.card[0])
    print("{a} vs. {b}".format(a = p1.card, b = p2.card))
    print("---------------------------")
```

...but that's what I want to change. I want what that function is doing to be executed more concisely inside of the attribute definitions upon handling of the instance. Basically my question is why can't these two attributes get their values directly from the first attribute that I define via "hand" passed to the init?

Any help would be appreciated, and more importantly, I think more than just solutions, it would help me even more to understand what I am misunderstanding about how attributes, instances, and instantiation and all that works so that I know where my thinking is wrong. Thanks!

```
import random
from random import shuffle
from collections import deque

class Deck():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ranks = {"Ace":14, "King":13, "Queen":12, "Jack":11, "10":10, "9":9, "8":8, "7":7, "6":6, "5":5, "4":4, "3":3, "2":2}
        self.suites = ["Heart", "Diamond", "Spade", "Club"]
        self.cards = []

    def create_cards(self):
        for suite in self.suites:
            for key in self.ranks.keys():
                self.cards.append(key + " " + suite)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(deck.cards)

deck = Deck()
deck.create_cards()
deck.shuffle()

class Player():
    def __init__(self, hand):
        self.name = "name"
        self.hand = hand
        self.card_number = 1
        self.card = self.hand[self.card_number].split()
        self.card_val = deck.ranks.get(self.card[0])

def war(bool, p1, p2):
    if bool == True:
        for player in [p1, p2]:
            player.card_number = 4
    else:
        for player in [p1, p2]:
            player.card_number = 0

p2 = Player(deque(deck.cards[::2]))
p1 = Player(deque(deck.cards[1::2]))

p2.name = "The Computer"

def get_card_vals(p1, p2):
    for player in [p1, p2]:
        player.card = player.hand[player.card_number].split()
        player.card_val = deck.ranks.get(player.card[0])
    print("{a} vs. {b}".format(a = p1.card, b = p2.card))
    print("---------------------------")

def cant_war_lose(winner, loser):
    print("{a} doesn't have enough cards to go to war, so {b} wins the Battle!".format(a = loser, b = winner))

def battle_win(winner, loser):
    print("{a} has run out of cards, therefore {b} has won via Battle!".format(a = loser, b = winner))

def play_cards(p1, p2):
    war(False, p1, p2)
    get_card_vals(p1, p2)
    if p1.card_val > p2.card_val:
        p1.hand.append(p2.hand.popleft())
        p1.hand.rotate(-1)
    elif p1.card_val == p2.card_val:
        if len(p1.hand) < 5 or len(p2.hand) < 5:
            if len(p1.hand) > len(p2.hand):
                cant_war_lose(p1.name, p2.name)
            else:
                cant_war_lose(p2.name, p1.name)
            return 0
        else:
            input("War is inititated! Press Enter to continue!")
            print("---------------------------")
            war(True, p1, p2)
            get_card_vals(p1, p2)
            if p1.card_val > p2.card_val:
                for i in range(0,5):
                    p1.hand.append(p2.hand.popleft())
                p1.hand.rotate(-5)
            elif p1.card_val < p2.card_val:
                for i in range(0,5):
                    p2.hand.append(p1.hand.popleft())
                p2.hand.rotate(-5)
            else:
                p1.hand.rotate(-1)
                p2.hand.rotate(-1)
    elif p1.card_val < p2.card_val:
        p2.hand.append(p1.hand.popleft())
        p2.hand.rotate(-1)
    if len(p1.hand) != 0 and len(p2.hand) != 0:
        input("After the last round of Battle, {a} now has {b} cards, and {c} now has {d} cards! Press Enter to continue!".format(a = p1.name, b = len(p1.hand), c = p2.name, d = len(p2.hand)))
        print("---------------------------")
    else:
        if len(p1.hand) > len(p2.hand):
            battle_win(p1.name, p2.name)
        else:
            battle_win(p2.name, p1.name)
        return 0

def game_run():
    run = 1

    p1.name = input("Player 1's name? ")
    print("---------------------------")

    while run == 1:
        if play_cards(p1, p2) == 0:
            run = 0

game_run()
```

Comment: use the `@property` decorator to make a [calculated property](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property#decorator)

Comment: Thanks! I actually had a feeling I could use it in that way, and had looked it up and all, but didn't know exactly how I would implement that. Could you by chance give me a working example based on my code snippet? I sort of understand how @property works, but if I could see it used on my own code, I think it would unlock my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `property` decorator to create a [calculated property](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property#decorator)

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, hand):
        self.name = "name"
        self.hand = hand
        self.card_number = 1

    @property
    def hand(self):
        return self._hand

    @hand.setter
    def hand(self, value):
        self._hand = value
        self.card = self._hand[self.card_number].split()
        self.card_val = deck.ranks.get(self.card[0])
```

Comment: Thanks!

I found this article which really breaks it down and concisely describes what's required to do this, and what's going on internally when you are using the @property decorator, the .getter, and .setter methods.

*For anybody who may be in the same boat that I was in when I posted this.*

https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/python-property/

Answer (score 0):

What you misunderstand is variables, not instances.  For instance, the attribute `card` is a scalar variable attached to the instance.  Assigning to it with

```
self.card = <blah>
```

does not bind it to `blah` for constant recomputation.  This is a value assignment, not a memory mapping.  If you want that long-term binding, you must either write the maintenance routine yourself -- which you've already done, in a way, with the consistent recomputation -- or you must assign a *mutable* reference to `self.card`, so that `card` refers to teh `same` object as the expression you created.

Given that you are consistently rotating and altering the hand, this is not feasible in your design.  Instead, simply write an access routine, perhaps `get_next_card(hand)`, which will rotate the hand, extract the card, and return the desired rank and suit.

If you plan to program more card games, you will also find it handy to define a `class card` and `class hand`, with appropriate support routines.  Maintain the card as a pair of integers; convert to strings only for printing.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Yes that definitely cleared up much of my confusion. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yay!  Do remember to choose a best answer when you're allowed, so that Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.  I think you get a few points for that, too.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wanted to compare a before and after of the problem & final solution, below is the working code for my specific issue. All I had to do was convert self.card and self.card_val to a calculated property. By passing in hand, and subsequently handling only hand, self.card & self.card_val are calculated, since every time I handle the instance of the class (by handling hand), these "method attributes" are being called and altered. Thanks for the input, guys!

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, hand):
        self.name = "name"
        self.card_number = 1
        self.hand = hand

    @property
    def card(self):
        return self.hand[self.card_number].split()

    @property
    def card_val(self):
        return deck.ranks.get(self.card[0])
```